# Mysql MEMORY table vs InnoDB table (many inserts, few reads)

Tags: mysql, optimization, innodb

I run my sites all on InnoDB tables which is working really well so far. Now I like to know what is going on in real-time on my sites, so I store each pageview (page, referrer, IP, hostname, etc) in an InnoDB table. There are about 100 inserts per second, and this table is only read once in a while when i'm browsing the logs.

I clean out the table every minute with a cron that removes old items. This leaves about 35.000 rows in that table on average, with a size of about 5MB.

Would it be easier on the server if I were to transfer the InnoDB table to a MEMORY table? As far as I can see this would save a lot of disk IO right? Restarting Mysql would result in a loss of data, but this does not matter in my case.

Question: In my case, would you recommend a Memory table over a InnoDB table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes I would. The conditions you mention (a lot of writes, periodic purging of data, data persistence not required) make it pretty much an ideal candidate for MEMORY.

Comment: I've switched to a MEMORY table, and performance is good. I did notice that my Lock Wait Ratio is kinda bad now. Current Lock Wait ratio = 1 : 570 is what Tuning-primer says. Anything I can do about that?

Comment: I believe L/W ratio is a server-wide indicatr, so you should probably ask it in another question. Also probably on http://serverfault.com/ instead of SO.

Comment: Ok thanks, I have asked it here: http://serverfault.com/questions/350364/high-lock-wait-ratio-in-mysql

Answer (score 0):

please optimize your innodb settings:

As long as you have configured InnoDB to use enough memory to hold your entire table (with innodb_buffer_pool_size), and there is not excessive pressure from other InnoDB tables on the same server, the data will remain in memory. If you're concerned about write performance (and again barring other uses of the same system) you can reduce durability to drastically increase write performance by setting innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 0 and disabling binary logging.

Using any sort of triggers with temporary tables will be a mess to maintain, and won't give you any benefits of transactionality on the temporary tables.

You can find more details right here:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit